# Is there any way to configure GitHub or ArgoCd to get notified for any updates done in JFrog Artifactory?

Tags: github, deployment, artifactory, webhooks, argocd

I am deploying microservices into Kubernetes,

So whenever a latest version of Docker image is pushed into Jrog Artifactory, it should notify Github or ArgoCD.

Is there any similar solution for this?

Comment: What part of GitHub would you want to be notified?  Where are you expecting to see this notification?  Are you looking to get a deployment notification for your pull request, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

If your Artifactory server is installed on-prem, the easiest way is to implement [a user plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/User+Plugins). You can use [the one from our user plugins repository](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/webhook) (and adapt it as needed), or write your own which will notify the services you need on events you need.

Here is a [blog post](https://jfrog.com/blog/automation-using-webhooks-in-jfrog-artifactory/) detailing how to use the existing plugin.

Also, a built-in feature is [on our roadmap](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-14103).